# I have point data on top of a soil map and i want to know what the soil type is for each of the 1000's of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop

It would be ideal to add a field to the attribute table of the point data that is describes the soil classification based on the soil classification map.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to the GIS Stack Exchange! Please make sure you take [the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with the Q&A format we follow here. A good question should be detailed and specific, giving other users enough information to replicate your situation. In this case, what format is the soil map you have? What have you tried so far? What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you running? Stack Exchange should be where you come after trying to solve this yourself and fail, not where you begin the process.

Comment: Hi, I have no idea what the format of the map is - I added it from ArcGIS online. It's name is Teagasc Soils ITM. I have tried extract values to points and some overlay tools and a few other things. I'm using ArcMap 10.2. I have been at this all day and it seems like it should be a pretty basic function for GIS but I just don't know where to look.

Comment: That layer is being served to ArcGIS Online as tiles, meaning they're non-interactive images. Go to the [TEAGASC website](http://gis.teagasc.ie/soils/downloads.php) and look through their downloads. Once you find the data you need, you can use Marcelo's answer to extract the data.

Comment: @JoshC it's a web feature layer. Shouldn't it be possible to extract feature values from a WFS?

Comment: @csk Can you link to where you found the feature layer? This is the only thing I found under the name Sean gave: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=82f09cca5c2c4221aa983d1a6d610c78

Comment: @JoshC That's the layer I was looking at. It's described on that page as a Web Service, but if you open the URL it's described as a Feature Layer with Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolygon. So...maybe I'm confused by the different terminology. https://secure.dccae.gov.ie/arcgis/rest/services/THIRD_PARTY/TeagascSoils/MapServer/0

Comment: @csk The crucial thing is that it's coming from a Map Server, rather than a Feature Server. Even though the layer itself is a polygon feature, the way it's being served limits the way it can be interacted with.

Comment: That makes sense. It's an issue with the soils layer itself. That's why none of the tools I tried to use would interact with it. Thanks for the help guys. I would not have known that otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the soil classification map is a vector file (polygons) and not a raster, you could use the [Intersect tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) and keep the default value for the **JoinAttributes** parameter. Take a look at the documentation for the **JoinAttributes** parameter:

> Determines which attributes from the input features will be
>   transferred to the output feature class.
>
> - ALL — All the attributes from the input features will be transferred to
>     the output feature class. This is the default.
> - NO_FID — All the
>     attributes except the FID from the input features will be transferred
>     to the output feature class.
> - ONLY_FID — Only the FID field from the
>     input features will be transferred to the output feature class

Another option is to use the [Spatial Join tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm). Tool's summary from the documentation:

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
>   relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the
>   join features are written to the output feature class.